# How to turn off the websocket after component unmounts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, websocket, next.js

this is my code snippet bellow,
I am trying to close the websocket connection after component unmounts, I just totally dont know how to do it
I am using this useEffect inside the same component I am also using useref to count the mounted count of the component so that the websocket doesn't creates more that 1 instance at a time

```
const mountedCount = useRef(0);

useEffect(() => {
    const handleWebsocket = () => {

        mountedCount.current++;

        const socketURL = 'socket url here'
        const socket = new WebSocket(socketURL);

        socket.onopen = () => {
            console.log('socket open')
        };

        socket.onclose = (closeEvent) => {
            if (closeEvent.wasClean) return;

            timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                handleWebsocket();
            }, envVariables.webSocketReconnectionTimeout);
        };
        socket.onerror = () => {
            console.log('error here')
        };

        socket.onmessage = (messageEvent) => {
            console.log('got the message')
        };

        return socket;
    };

    if (mountedCount.current === 0) {
        handleWebsocket();
    }
    return () => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
}, [
    dispatch,
    userData.userInformation,
    wss.connectionStatus
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const mountedCount = useRef(0);
const [currentSocket,setCurrentSocket]=useState(null)
useEffect(() => {
    const handleWebsocket = () => {

        mountedCount.current++;

        const socketURL = 'socket url here'
        const socket = new WebSocket(socketURL);

        socket.onopen = () => {
            console.log('socket open')
        };

        socket.onclose = (closeEvent) => {
            if (closeEvent.wasClean) return;

            timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                handleWebsocket();
            }, envVariables.webSocketReconnectionTimeout);
        };
        socket.onerror = () => {
            console.log('error here')
        };

        socket.onmessage = (messageEvent) => {
            console.log('got the message')
        };

        return socket;
    };

    if (mountedCount.current === 0) {
       setCurrentSocket(handleWebsocket());
    }
    return () => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        currentSocket?.close();
    };
}, [
    dispatch,
    userData.userInformation,
    wss.connectionStatus
]);
```

Comment: I can't do that because socket variable is inside the handleWebsocket() function

Comment: Thanks mate this was helpful, just want to point that useState will have inital type as WebSocket

Answer (score 0):

or you can declare socket variable in one upper scope:

```
const mountedCount = useRef(0);

useEffect(() => {
    let socket
    const handleWebsocket = () => {

        mountedCount.current++;

        const socketURL = 'socket url here'
        socket = new WebSocket(socketURL);

        socket.onopen = () => {
            console.log('socket open')
        };

        socket.onclose = (closeEvent) => {
            if (closeEvent.wasClean) return;

            timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                handleWebsocket();
            }, envVariables.webSocketReconnectionTimeout);
        };
        socket.onerror = () => {
            console.log('error here')
        };

        socket.onmessage = (messageEvent) => {
            console.log('got the message')
        };

        return socket;
    };

    if (mountedCount.current === 0) {
        handleWebsocket();
    }
    return () => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        socket.close()
    };
}, [
    dispatch,
    userData.userInformation,
    wss.connectionStatus
]);
```